# minimum of list to maximum of value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently have a list in Javascript:

let x = [1.0, 2.5, 5.0, 20.0, 50.0, 100.0, 500.0, 2000.0, 5000.0]
where each value of this is a dollar coin.

My problem is the following, I need some equation for Javascript to choose the smallest possible number of coins to reach the maximum in the desired value.

I'll give an example:

I need as few coins as possible to max out at 5.5USD. I would use a coin of 2.5USD and 3 coins of 1.0USD to arrive at 5.5USD.

Restriction: The value obtained cannot exceed the desired value.

What math function would I use for this? Or does anyone know a technical name given to this type of equation for me to look up? Well, there was never anything like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write logic , no inbuilt function as such can be done easily by reduce !

```js
let a = [1.0, 2.5, 5.0, 20.0, 50.0, 100.0, 500.0, 2000.0, 5000.0];

let query = 80.0;

while (query > 0) {
  //find closest maximum number
  const output = a.filter(t => t <= query).reduce((prev, curr) => Math.abs(curr - query) < Math.abs(prev - query) ? curr : prev);

  query = query - output;
  console.log(output);
}
```

Comment: This is amazing, it came very close to what I was looking for, but whenever I set the value to 80, for example, it returns 100, or when I set 40, it returns 50.
I'll edit the question, because I forgot to put the restrictions, and this is one of them: the value obtained cannot exceed the desired one, it needs to "try" to reach the maximum of the desired value!

Comment: I have updated the code , just added the filter condition to filter out the values

Comment: This worked for me! I had done something very similar with Python, but it had resulted in almost 20 lines of code and I was at a loss as to how to do it in Javascript! Thank you very much!